# R how to test a keras text classification model once the model is done?

Tags: r, keras, classification

I started this project from Keras using r: https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tutorials/beginners/basic-ml/tutorial_basic_text_classification/
I used my own data etc and the model gave me an 86% accuracy.
Now I want to test new string inputs such as **test_text <- "Testing string with many words"** now I want to plug this new text into the model and tell me which category it falls in. For example, my project has text as tweets from users and the second column categorizes the text as "yes" or "no" for bullying.

Thanks!

edit: I vectorized my text to have the input as a matrix:

```
text <- c("you suck kid grow up")
num_words <- 10000
max_length <- 50
text_vectorization_test <- layer_text_vectorization(
  max_tokens = num_words, 
  output_sequence_length = max_length, 
)

text_vectorization_test %>% 
  adapt(text)

get_vocabulary(text_vectorization_test)

text <- text_vectorization(matrix(text, ncol = 1))
text
```

````
[[1 1 5 7 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]], shape=(1, 50), dtype=int64)```
````

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "text_vectorization_4" (type TextVectorization).

When using `TextVectorization` to tokenize strings, the input rank must be 1 or the last shape dimension must be 1. Received: inputs.shape=(None, 50) with rank=2

Call arguments received by layer "text_vectorization_4" (type TextVectorization):
• inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 50), dtype=string)

See `reticulate::py_last_error()` for details

Comment: `predict(your_model, text)`?

Comment: I get this error check edit!